# Adding indicator values by using a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, vector

I'm relatively inexperienced with R. I have a vector of true and false values. I want to make these numeric (i.e., 0 or 1). I have tried to write this for loop, but there are several syntax errors that I don't know how to fix.

```
indY <- rep(NA, nrow(dat)) # making an empty vector
# use for loop to fill each entry with either 0 or 1
for (i in 1:length(y)) {
  if newy[i] == TRUE:
    indY[i] == 1
  else:
    indY[i] == 0
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fine :

```
as.numeric(y)
```

Assuming `y` is a vector of TRUEs and FALSEs.

Answer (score 3):

For bonus points, use `+`:

```
y <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
+y
#[1] 1 1 0 1
```

This coerces `y` to numeric and returns the vector.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df$y <- ifelse(df$y, 1, 0)
```